# What is the difference between simple interest and simple discounting?

Tags: finance

I have been given the following statements:

"**Simple interest:** $C$ now $\equiv (1+in)C$ in $n$ years; $C$ in $n$ years $\equiv \frac{C}{1+in}$ now.

**Simple discounting:**
$C$ in $n$ years $\equiv (1−dn)C$ now; $C$ now $\equiv \frac{C}{1-dn}$ in $n$ years.

Where $d=\frac{i}{1+i}$"

These statements imply that simple interest and simple discounting are not equivalent, since the statements do not equate to one another. Why is this, and **what is the difference between simple interest and simple discounting?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong formula for d.

$C_{0c}$: present value (simple compound)

$C_{0d}$: present value (simple discount)

$C_{nd}$: future value (simple discount)

$C_{nc}$: future value (simple compound)

$C_{nc}=C_{0c}\cdot (1+in)$

$C_{0d}=C_{nd}\cdot \frac{1}{1-d\cdot n}=C_{nd}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{i\cdot n}{1+i\cdot n}}$

with $\boxed{d=\frac{i}{1+i\cdot n}}$

Here I have a different expression for d.

The future value of the simple compound has to be equal to the present value of the simple discount. This is your asked connection.

$C_{0c}\cdot (1+in)=C_{nd}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{i\cdot n}{1+i\cdot n}}$

$C_{0c}$ and $C_{nd}$ can be cancelled, because they are equal, too.

$(1+in)= \frac{1}{1-\frac{i\cdot n}{1+i\cdot n}}$

Multiplying the equation by the denominator of the RHS.

$(1+in)\cdot \left( 1-\frac{i\cdot n}{1+i\cdot n} \right)=1$

Now you can proof, if the equation is true.